# Ember.js use link-to helper in custom helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli and getting an exception when trying to use a helper within a helper.

The following line ...

```
return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'](this, args);
```

Causes the exception ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ember.default.Handlebars.helpers.link-to.apply is not a function
```

Also I was trying to use the following elsewhere in the code and got a similar error, is the cause the same?

```
Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, MyView, options);
```

Exception ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ember.default.Handlebars.helpers.view.call is not a function
```

Comment: Can you apply these helpers in your template?

Comment: As of now I am not using a template. My goal is to create a helper that uses link-to for internal ember links or a standard <a href...> link for external links.